# How can simulate mouse clicks in a cron job on a headless machine?

Tags: xorg, scripts, mouse, cron

I have a headless machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I'd like to set up a cron job to daily click some buttons on a web page.  I often use X2Go, and I know I could manually open an X session and use xdotool to simulate the clicks, but I'd like to run this script unattended.  Should I, or, is it possible to have a shell script open an X session without a display and mouse click in that?

I've set my machine to not start lightdm on startup, so I'm not using lightdm at all.  My graphical access is through X2Go.

I have physical access to the machine, but I'd like to avoid connecting a keyboard, mouse, or display to it.  The mouse click asks to download a file from the web page.  I don't think there's a way for me to get the file without clicking on the button.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have a _headless_ machine running an X session?

Comment: @terdon "I often use X2Go".

Comment: @the_Seppi "I'd like to set up a cron job to daily click some buttons on a web page." I need to interact with a service that I can only access through a graphical web page.

Comment: can't you call the button's target with i.e. curl?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know much about X2Go but doesn't it need a running X server to connect to? I'm just confused since you called the machine headless and yet seem to have X on it. Anyway, if you do have a working X installed, why not set the system up to log you into your GUI session automatically on startup. That way, you will always have a running X session when needed.

Comment: @the_Seppi I seriously doubt it. The web page has lots of complicated things that I don't know how to dig through like Flash, CSS, and javascript.

Comment: @terdon No, I have my Ubuntu machine set to not start lightdm on startup.  If I plugged in a display, I wouldn't see any graphics.  X2Go runs a remote X session through SSH.  I guess I probably could start X locally and run the xdotool script from the console, but I'd really rather not.

Comment: @aswine then please [edit] your question and tell us that. We need to know the details of your setup and the details of what you're trying to achieve in order to help.

Comment: @terdon Okay, I thought saying it was headless was enough, but I guess you'd like me to say that I'm not using lightdm.

Comment: Well, headless normally implies no screen, no keyboard, no mouse and certainly no X, to me anyway. So, yes, it was confusing. I also asked you to explain exactly what you need to do and what your requirements are (for example, that you don't want to have X loaded automatically).

Comment: @terdon Sorry for the confusion. My understanding of "headless" is that there's no keyboard, mouse, or display plugged into the machine in question.  A keyboard, mouse, display, and graphics could be elsewhere to interact with it.